# cannot understand behavior of revealing module

Tags: javascript, closures, revealing-module-pattern

I'm studying closures and revealing module pattern. It seemed to me I got it, but then during practice i found this strange "bug".
Here's the code:

```
    const module=(function(){
    let counter=1;
  let incrCounter=function(){
  counter++;
  console.log(counter)
  }
  return { counter, incrCounter}
})();

module.incrCounter(); ///expected:2; output:2;
module.incrCounter(); ///expected:3; output:3
module.incrCounter(); ///expected:4 output:4

module.counter=1; 
module.incrCounter(); ///expected:2; output:5
module.counter; ///expected:5 (for some reason) ; output:1
```

I reread "You don't know JS" about closures. It has to work! I return an object with property "counter", so I should have the direct access to it. But it seems that i creating a new, local variable with the same name, and not updating the counter I want to. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The inner counter variable is not accessible here to outside the function, nor does "module.counter=1" get access to the inner variable.  you are on the right way to understand closures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `return {counter, incrCounter}`, you are saying:

- Copy the value of `counter` into the `counter` property of the return object
- Then copy the value of `incrCounter` into the `incrCounter` property of the return object

You are **not** saying to expose the internal counter variable, which means modifications to `module.counter` simply modify the copy, not the actual value. You can fix this by storing it in an object:

```js
const module = (function() {
    let ret = {counter: 1};
    let incrCounter = function() {
        ret.counter ++;
        console.log(ret.counter);
    };
    ret.incrCounter = incrCounter;
    return ret;
})();
```

Or, just using objects and `this`:

```js
const module = {
    counter: 1,
    incrCounter() {
        this.counter ++;
        console.log(this.counter);
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh, so I am passing the copy, not the pointer to the real counter. Got it. Thank you